# Neo4j - Community ed. v. 3.3.1 Uploading data from csv files

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I observe that uploading files from browser is not setting the properties. Here is the code:

```
USING PERIODIC COMMIT
LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM 
'file:///Databases.csv' AS line
WITH line

CREATE (database:DATABASE {databaseName: line.DatabaseName})
SET database.server = line.Server;
```

Just the DATABASE-nodes are created with an "id" which is neo4j-spesific. Is there a mistake in the code? or should I use noe4j-shell/console? If so, how can I start it on windows?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please, edit your question and post the output of `USING PERIODIC COMMIT
LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM 
'file:///Databases.csv' AS line
WITH line LIMIT 1
RETURN line`

Comment: Also, add some lines of your CSV file.

Comment: Also, see about FIELDTERMINATOR if your import results displease you.

FYK, id is a technical id. 
Internal reference. It may be reused by db after corresponding nodes are deleted. So never use it as a reference.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to `RETURN line LIMIT 1` (instead of creating the node) and check the text view to ensure that your property names are as you expect. Maybe there are spaces in the headers that are causing the resulting `line` property names to have leading or trailing spaces.